# How to specify pattern dynamically using file and get files according to pattern from that directory?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell

I am  newbie of shell script. Correct if I am wrong.

I have one file called `ignorefileslist` in which it has file's names and patterns like /trunk/* means ignore all files from trunk.

I am able to get line of file which holds this pattern but unable to find out how to execute those pattern to get files matching that pattern. For example files inside /trunk folder for /trunk/* pattern.

ignorefileslist.txt :

```
/.settings
/.project
/branches/staging/test.php
/trunk/index.php
/trunk/*.php
/trunk/*
```

Here is my code :

```
if grep -q "*" "$HOME/$REPONAME/ignorablefileslist.txt";then

   filewithpattern=`cat $HOME/$REPONAME/ignorablefileslist.txt | grep "*" `

   echo "It contains pattern $filewithpattern"    
fi
```

Output :

```
It contains pattern /trunk/*.php /trunk/*
```

How can I both /trunk/* and  /trunk/*.php regex to get files accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

Change your grep command like below to print the filenames which contains `/trunk/*` or `/trunk/*.php` strings.

```
grep -lP '/trunk/\*(\.php)?' *.*
```

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason you need to keep your conditional statement intact then you could use a loop and process substitution to avoid a subshell.

```
if grep -q "*" ignorefileslist.txt; then while read filewithpattern; do echo "It contains pattern $filewithpattern"; done < <( grep "*" ignorefileslist.txt ); fi
```